# how to extract key and value from json content?

Tags: php, laravel

what I have tried is this.

```
public function toArrayss(){

        $json = '{"notificationType":"Bounce","bounce":{"feedbackId":"010201762c4054a2-424cab55-f6b7-420c-8f51-f1f13cb8b702-000000","bounceType":"Transient","bounceSubType":"General","bouncedRecipients":[{"emailAddress":"chintu@mailinatorc.com","action":"failed","status":"4.4.7","diagnosticCode":"smtp; 554 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes.<421 4.4.0 Unable to lookup DNS for mailinatorc.com>"}],"timestamp":"2020-12-04T05:36:22.000Z","reportingMTA":"dsn; a4-1.smtp-out.eu-west-1.amazonses.com"},"mail":{"timestamp":"2020-12-03T13:58:22.222Z","source":"ooionline@opsimplify.com","sourceArn":"arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:128134649499:identity/opsimplify.com","sourceIp":"3.248.44.136","sendingAccountId":"128134649499","messageId":"0102017628e5910e-f8d2fba5-c25f-4109-8571-246ca3c983b2-000000","destination":["chintu@mailinatorc.com"],"headersTruncated":false,"headers":[{"name":"Received","value":"from sharabh.ooionline.com (ec2-3-248-44-136.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [3.248.44.136]) by email-smtp.amazonaws.com with SMTP (SimpleEmailService-d-8DMC1AGE7) id zcEZl2C63kMsDHYhlI2W for chintu@mailinatorc.com; Thu, 03 Dec 2020 13:58:22 +0000 (UTC)"},{"name":"Date","value":"Thu, 3 Dec 2020 14:58:22 +0100"},{"name":"To","value":"chintu@mailinatorc.com"},{"name":"From","value":"OPSimplify <ooionline@opsimplify.com>"},{"name":"Reply-To","value":"Email Notification <noreply@opsimplify.com>"},{"name":"Subject","value":"Votre accès à la plateforme collaborative SHARABH"},{"name":"Message-ID","value":"<PhTQOVF4ZuRS5icap8Bt6u6KCcBd3l2ihs2RPqYmpI@sharabh.ooionline.com>"},{"name":"X-Mailer","value":"PHPMailer 6.0.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)"},{"name":"MIME-Version","value":"1.0"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text/html; charset=UTF-8"}],"commonHeaders":{"from":["OPSimplify <ooionline@opsimplify.com>"],"replyTo":["Email Notification <noreply@opsimplify.com>"],"date":"Thu, 3 Dec 2020 14:58:22 +0100","to":["chintu@mailinatorc.com"],"messageId":"<PhTQOVF4ZuRS5icap8Bt6u6KCcBd3l2ihs2RPqYmpI@sharabh.ooionline.com>","subject":"Votre accès à la plateforme collaborative SHARABH"}}}
';
        $objs = json_decode($json,true);

        $key = ['notificationType','bounceType','bounceSubType','timestamp'];
        foreach ($objs as $obj => $values )  {
            // echo $obj . ":". $values;
            dd($objs);
            // echo $values ;

        }
```

Can anyone help me in extracting keys and values like notificationType,bounceType,timestamp etc;
It would be great help for me if anyone help me achieving this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json_decode decode a string converting it in php data structures: array or object. Check docs for [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

You get object if you pass the second parameter as false:

```
<?php

$decoded = json_decode(..., false);

echo $decoded->notificationType;
```

And get associative array if pass true as the second parameter

```
<?php

$decoded = json_decode(..., true);

echo $decoded['notificationType'];
```

Your problem is that you are handling the returned array as a collection of notifications. Note that $objs only contains a single notification object.

```
<?php
function toArrayss() {
    
    $json = '{"notificationType":"Bounce","bounce":{"feedbackId":"010201762c4054a2-424cab55-f6b7-420c-8f51-f1f13cb8b702-000000","bounceType":"Transient","bounceSubType":"General","bouncedRecipients":[{"emailAddress":"chintu@mailinatorc.com","action":"failed","status":"4.4.7","diagnosticCode":"smtp; 554 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes.<421 4.4.0 Unable to lookup DNS for mailinatorc.com>"}],"timestamp":"2020-12-04T05:36:22.000Z","reportingMTA":"dsn; a4-1.smtp-out.eu-west-1.amazonses.com"},"mail":{"timestamp":"2020-12-03T13:58:22.222Z","source":"ooionline@opsimplify.com","sourceArn":"arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:128134649499:identity/opsimplify.com","sourceIp":"3.248.44.136","sendingAccountId":"128134649499","messageId":"0102017628e5910e-f8d2fba5-c25f-4109-8571-246ca3c983b2-000000","destination":["chintu@mailinatorc.com"],"headersTruncated":false,"headers":[{"name":"Received","value":"from sharabh.ooionline.com (ec2-3-248-44-136.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [3.248.44.136]) by email-smtp.amazonaws.com with SMTP (SimpleEmailService-d-8DMC1AGE7) id zcEZl2C63kMsDHYhlI2W for chintu@mailinatorc.com; Thu, 03 Dec 2020 13:58:22 +0000 (UTC)"},{"name":"Date","value":"Thu, 3 Dec 2020 14:58:22 +0100"},{"name":"To","value":"chintu@mailinatorc.com"},{"name":"From","value":"OPSimplify <ooionline@opsimplify.com>"},{"name":"Reply-To","value":"Email Notification <noreply@opsimplify.com>"},{"name":"Subject","value":"Votre accès à la plateforme collaborative SHARABH"},{"name":"Message-ID","value":"<PhTQOVF4ZuRS5icap8Bt6u6KCcBd3l2ihs2RPqYmpI@sharabh.ooionline.com>"},{"name":"X-Mailer","value":"PHPMailer 6.0.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)"},{"name":"MIME-Version","value":"1.0"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text/html; charset=UTF-8"}],"commonHeaders":{"from":["OPSimplify <ooionline@opsimplify.com>"],"replyTo":["Email Notification <noreply@opsimplify.com>"],"date":"Thu, 3 Dec 2020 14:58:22 +0100","to":["chintu@mailinatorc.com"],"messageId":"<PhTQOVF4ZuRS5icap8Bt6u6KCcBd3l2ihs2RPqYmpI@sharabh.ooionline.com>","subject":"Votre accès à la plateforme collaborative SHARABH"}}}
';
    $objs = json_decode($json, true);
    
    $key = ['notificationType', 'bounceType', 'bounceSubType', 'timestamp'];
    foreach ($objs as $obj => $values) {
        // echo $obj . ":". $values;
        dd($objs);
        // echo $values ;
        
    }
}
```

Modify your code like this

```
<?php

public function toArrays($json) {
    
    // if the json string contains a collection of notifications
    // this line returns an array that contains multiple notifications
    // in the other hand, if the json string contains a single notification object
    // this line returns a single notification as array
    return json_decode($json, true);
}
```

In this way you receive the json content as parameter and toArrays method only decode it and returns as array. You can iterate it with foreach, and can access to the indexes in the traditional way.

```
<?php

$asArray = $someObject->asArrays($someJsonString);

echo $asArray['some_property'];

foreach ($asArray as $key => $value) {
    echo ">" . $key;

    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $subKey => $subValue) {
            echo ">>>" . $subKey . "\n";
            echo ">>>>" . $subValue . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo ">>" . $value . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: it is giving undefined index. Because bounceType is inside notificationType array inside bounce array.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Check that you need know the path to the desired attribute.

Comment: This will just print the value I want to print key and pair because later I have to save this response in database.

Comment: be aware that the notification object is a complex object. You can iterate it with foreach ($notification as $key => $value), but value could be an object/array by it self.

Comment: if you are more specific about do you want to do, i can offer the solution. But about the question, at this time you must to know how to extract keys and values.